# Who are these two people in the third opening of Attack on Titan?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In the third opening of Attack on Titan we see a man and a baby holding hands. Does anyone know who these two people are?
I can't remember seeing them in the manga.

Or -if they are not "real" characters- what does this scene want to allude to? I can't think of any symbolism in this picture...
[image: two people holding hands]

Comment: AoT openings often contains a lot of symbolisms rather than actual scenes. In this case, it *is* only a symbolic picture, as far as I know

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Any idea on what this picture could mean?

Comment: Same with the women holding the baby in the beginning. We don't know who they are.

Comment: While I agree that symbolism is rife in all three openings, and that a lot of the animations in all three openings are not actual scenes, I also think that the content in the openings tend to have some basis in reality or in the very least give us additional insight into the story. As for this image, that definitely looks like a military uniform on the left. It could just be there for symbolism or it may be a concept that is later revealed in the story.

Comment: Thanks guys. I asked out of pure curiosity. I thought that I may have missed something or that there was sone kind of hidden symbolism I didn't get.

Comment: As for the women that seem to appear at each of the openings, at least in openings 1 and 2, both women were the representation of a wall. In the first opening it was Wall Maria, in the second opening it was Wall Rose, and in the third opening, it's likely it is still Wall Rose but another representation.

Comment: Most probably. And regarding the child she's carrying in her hands... the only representation of a child I can think of are the children of Ymir. Maybe it means the woman protects her child just as the walls protect the children of Ymir? Idfk... The ending is much easier to analyze haha

Comment: @Ryota: Here's another interpretation: Eren's key (to his father's basement) has been somewhat absent. However, the first time we see Eren in season 2, he talks to himself about the key. Likely, this is a way to keep reminding viewers that the key still exists. It is related to his father, so it's possible that the image you linked is Eren and his father. This may serve both as a reminder of his father's (basement's) important to the story, and also a foreshadowing of a scene that will be explored later in the show, maybe in connection to Eren's dad's involvement with the show's plot.

Comment: Here it is in October, this has been bumped. But I am commenting to push it back up. Does anyone know about this?

Comment: @kaz Comments don't bump posts, only edits and answers do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This scene is depicted from *Shingeki no Kyojin* manga chapter 86, "That Day".

> Grisha Yeager and Dina Fritz got married during the rise of Eldia and had a baby. This baby was named Zeke, which further betrayed whole Eldia and joined the Marley Forces.
>
>  [image: Grisha holding Zeke on his arms, with caption "His name was Zeke."]

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! We hope you can enjoy and participate further on this site. Meanwhile, I decided to add a proper spoiler block using `>!`. Feel free to [edit] and improve it, or rollback if it doesn't suit your style. Thanks!

Comment: While that seems legit, do we have any evidence that the baby on the opening is this one?

Comment: @Ikaros SNK have some easter eggs like this in OP/ED. If  you have watched the season 3 ED, it has some major spoilers of upcoming season 4. Trust me, this kid is zeke(the half blood prince) and in next season they will reach the basement.

Comment: I am not disproving your answer, just asking if there are any *solid* evidence about the identity of the baby. Yeah, I am reading the manga and I agree that the ED is a big easter egg.

Comment: I'm afraid @Ikaros is right. Although it seems plausible, there is no evidence at the moment.

Comment: Grisha and Zeke seem likely to me. Incidentally, I'd like to add that we see another picture of a baby holding their father's hands in chapter 99, namely Karl Fritz (King of the Walls) and his unnamed child. However, it's unlikely it's them because this chapter came out after season 2. Furthermore, Karl Fritz wears a robe and not a suit.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is not totally explicit, but, according to this Website (and many others): http://aminoapps.com/page/shonen-amino/4316391/alerta-spoiler-primera-parte

These are hands from Grisha and Zeke.

Answer (score -1):

This is the hand of Eren Yeager and his son/daughter with Historia Reiss/Fritz, could be Historia Yeager in the future. Though this theory cannot still be supported yet by the manga, but I assume that this is where it leads, the future, based on what the manga is currently potraying.

Comment: I don't know man. Seems kinda far-fetched if you ask me...